# What is the correct term for using a verb as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, participles, headline-english

My local newspaper has a confusing headline today: [*“Littlehampton rescue after person thrown from town inflatable“*](https://www.theargus.co.uk/news/18639302.littlehampton-rescue-person-thrown-town-inflatable/).

I am having difficulty working out whether this is (a) grammatically correct (should it just be “towed” rather than “town”?) and (b) what the best way would be to remove the reader’s confusion between town (the noun) and town (the what? some kind of participle of tow?). If I knew the correct term for using a verb as an adjective like this I might be able to Google it, but I don’t know if it’s a participle, a gerund or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's *actual* example is invalid - *shown, blown, grown, known, thrown* are all valid Past Participle forms, but not *town* or *crown* (which are "regular" verbs with PP ***towed*** and ***crowed***). But if it *was* a valid, use, it would be called a...

> **participial adjective** [(Lexico.com)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/participial_adjective)
> *An adjective that is a participle in origin and form, such as **burned, cutting, engaged***.

And [thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486), tells us it's also called a **verbal adjective** or a **deverbal adjective.**

---

Another potentially relevant term from my second link above is ***pseudo-participial adjective*** - used to identify the *increasing number of adjectives [that] are coined by adding **-ing** or **-ed** not to verbs but to nouns.* Examples of which include ***enterprising, neighboring, talented,*** and ***skilled*** (there is no verb ***to enterprise***, for example).

Comment: The answer to OP's actual question is 'typo'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Aw, spoilsport! I think it's much more interesting to suppose it was an "almost excusable" creatively coined Past Participle! If I had a 5-year-old child come out with ***town*** for ***towed*** (or ***crown*** for ***crowed / crew***) I'd be chuffed to bits!